# Given points A, B, and C, how to determine whether both angles ABC and ACB are acute?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I'm trying to figure out an efficient way to determine whether, given the x and y coordinates of points A, B, and C, both the angle going from A to B to C and the angle from A to C to B are less than 90 degrees.

Basically, if Point A falls within the green area in this image, [image: strip defined by opposite points B and C on edges]the method should return true, and false otherwise.

I could think of some convoluted ways to do this, but I feel like there should be a simpler one. Since my program will be doing it a lot, an efficient solution would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Nice question, but this belongs on the [Math Stack Exchange site](https://math.stackexchange.com), because it only has to do with math, and not programming.

Comment: if you show what you tried, and also tell us the preferred programming language for the solution, you might possibly avoid your question being closed

Comment: please replace the link to the image on an external site with the image itself

Comment: @WalterTross - Sorry, but since I'm a new user, I don't think it will let me do that yet. I've posted my question over on [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214624/given-points-a-b-and-c-how-to-determine-whether-both-angles-abc-and-acb-are-a) if you'd like to answer it there.

Comment: actually I think my answer is more appropriate here, also because it is in a form that lends itself to optimization if the check has to be repeated for several points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) BA·BC (i.e., |BA||BC|cosθ, where θ is the angle between BA and BC), to be between 0 and BC<sup>2</sup>. In Python:

```
def in_strip(ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy):
    bcx = cx - bx
    bcy = cy - by
    strip_width_squared = bcx * bcx + bcy * bcy
    bax = ax - bx
    bay = ay - by
    dot_product = bax * bcx + bay * bcy
    return 0 < dot_product < strip_width_squared
```

If the dot product is less than 0, the point A lies outside the strip on the side closer to B, if it is greater than BC<sup>2</sup>, it lies outside the strip on the side closer to C.

You can look at the dot product BA·BC as the product of two lengths: the length of the vector BC, |BC|, and the length of the component of the vector BA parallel to the vector BC (i.e., the projection onto a line parallel to it), |BA|cosθ. This component is 0 when A is on the edge of the strip that contains B, and it is BC when A is on the edge of the  strip that contains C.

Using the above dot product saves you almost half of the calculations if you have to check several points for inclusion in the same strip. E.g., like this (can be improved):

```
class Strip:
    def __init__(self, bx, by, cx, cy):
        self.bx,  self.by  = bx, by
        self.bcx, self.bcy = cx - bx, cy - by
        self.width_squared = self.bcx * self.bcx + self.bcy * self.bcy

    def contains(self, ax, ay):
        bax, bay = ax - self.bx, ay - self.by
        return 0 < bax * self.bcx + bay * self.bcy < self.width_squared
```